# Access Path Denied when iterating through C: drive

Tags: c#

The problem is that when I'm inside folder for example in my desktop or it could be any other folder, my program is working smoothly, but once I try to iterate every file in every directory and subdirectories with "C:" drive as a path it throws me an error "Access path denied".

If i use a try/catch before iterating through folder it only shows me like 7 files and stop.

My code looks like that :

```
        try
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                    textBox1.AppendText(file + "\r\n");


                    cpt++;
                    textBox2.AppendText(cpt.ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
       
        return cpt;
```

and the outputed values for textBox1 and textBox2 are :

```
C:\appverifUI.dll 1
C:\bootTel.dat 2
C:\DumpStack.log.tmp 3
C:\hiberfil.sys 4
C:\pagefile.sys 5
C:\swapfile.sys 6
C:\vfcompat.dll 7
```

I need it to work on .NET framework

Comment: Well, yes, of course. C: is usually the system drive, and on the system drive there are a number of folders and files (both related to the OS and the installed programs) that are not accessible by a normal, unprivileged user account. Use the Directory.EnumerateFiles overload that's accepting an EnumerationOptions instance, which allows you to specify to ignore inaccessible folders/files.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace could you please either answer this question with the right code or either just tell me what should I put exactly after the SearchOption overload

Comment: My apologies, but you can look up the documentation as easily as everybody else. Look, i am as lazy as it gets, so... uh... well...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I asked you that because I just tried and apparently it's not working with .NET framework

Comment: Uh... that's of course bad. Can you upgrade to .NET 5 or is there something that keeps you on .NET Framework 4.8?

Comment: If you are stuck on .NET Framework 4.8, perhaps [AlphaFS](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS) can help you out. From its readme: "_Feature Highlights: [...] Folder/file enumerator supporting custom filtering and error reporting/recovery (access denied exceptions)_".

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I can't migrate to .NET for the moment but I will soon, do you think that there is still a solution for a black sheep running .NET framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Normal applications can't access every folder in a machine. When they do, they get an Access Denied exception. You can avoid this by using the [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-6.0#system-io-directory-enumeratefiles(system-string-system-string-system-io-enumerationoptions)) overload that accepts an [EnumerationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=net-6.0) parameter with [IgnoreInaccessible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions.ignoreinaccessible?view=net-6.0#system-io-enumerationoptions-ignoreinaccessible) set to `true` :

```
var options=new EnumerationOptions { 
    IgnoreInaccessible = true,
    RecurseSubdirectories = true
};
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\", "*.*",options))
{
...
}
```

Comment: This is not working for .NET framework unfortunately :(

Comment: Time to upgrade then. .NET Core isn't new by any measure and .NET Framework is essentially in maintenance mode. All new developments go to .NET Core